# JButton ArrayList not updating correctly on tick?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a crude idle game (think [CookieClicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)) using the default JFrame gui. The unit of currency is 'clicks' and once enough 'clicks' are earned, the player should be able to click a JButton corresponding to the autoclicker they can buy. However, only the last 'autoclicker' added to the ArrayList of autoclickers becomes available at the correct time, and if it is clicked, all other JButtons take on its properties. If possible, could you help me figure out the problem? Disclaimer: probably a bunch of troubleshooting.

Here is my Main class:
(I have the extra JButtons and AutoClickers commented out so it works sort of as intended)

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame /*implements Runnable*/{

    static double clickCount = 0D;
    static double cpst = 0D;
    static JFrame frameMain = new JFrame("Clicker - Evan");
    static JLabel labelCount = new JLabel("Click Count: " + clickCount);
    static JLabel labelcps = new JLabel("Click Per Second: " + cpst);
    static ArrayList<AutoClicker> clickers = new ArrayList<AutoClicker>(/*Arrays.asList(AutoClicker("Mouse", 1, 10))*/);
    static ArrayList<JButton> buttonAuto = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    static JButton buttonMain = new JButton("Click");

    private static boolean running = false;
    //private Thread thread;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        init();
        run();
    }

    static long lastTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    final static double amountOfTicks2 = 2D;
    static double ns2 = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks2;
    double delta2 = 0;

    //Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXxaPQ_fQo
    static class buttonMainAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            clickCount++;

            System.out.println("refresh?");


        }
    }
    static class buttonBuyAction implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int fromNumber = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());

            clickCount -= (int)clickers.get( fromNumber ).getCost();
            clickers.get( fromNumber ).buy();
            buttonAuto.get( fromNumber ).setText(clickers.get( fromNumber ).getNumberOwned() 
                    + " " + clickers.get( fromNumber ).getName() + "(s) - Cost: " + (int)clickers.get( fromNumber ).getCost() + " Clicks");

            System.out.println("+1 " + clickers.get( fromNumber ).getName());
        }
    }


    //Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSdKBQMdlLM
    //Source 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFRuEgEdO9Q&list=PLah6faXAgguMnTBs3JnEJY0shAc18XYQZ&index=4
    public static void run(){

        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;

        //init();

        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }

            render();
        }
    }

    private static void init(){
        clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Mouse", .1, 10));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Monkey", .36, 50));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Toddler", .5, 250));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Pre-Teen", 1, 700));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Angsty Teen", 1.5, 1500));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Intern", 2.5, 2000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Newbie", 5, 4000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("HR Staffer", 10, 10000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Misc. Staffer", 15, 12000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Media Analyst", 30, 100000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("CEO", 50, 800000));
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Researcher", 80, 2000000));
//      
//      
//      clickers.add(new AutoClicker("Sacrifice Leader", 500, 99999999));

        System.out.println("clickers.size()=\t" + clickers.size());

        frameMain.setVisible(true);

        frameMain.setSize(800, 600);
        frameMain.setResizable(false);
        frameMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameMain.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        frameMain.add(buttonMain);
        buttonMain.addActionListener(new buttonMainAction() );


        buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Mouse(s) - Cost: 10 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Monkey(s) - Cost: 50 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Toddler(s) - Cost: 250 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Pre-Teen(s) - Cost: 700 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Angsty Teen(s) - Cost: 1500 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Intern(s) - Cost: 2000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Newbie(s) - Cost: 4000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 HR Staffer(s) - Cost: 10000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Misc. Staffer(s) - Cost: 12000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Media Analyst(s) - Cost: 100000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 CEO(s) - Cost: 800000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Researcher(s) - Cost: 2000000 Clicks"));
//      buttonAuto.add(new JButton("0 Sacrafice Leader(s) - Cost: 99999999 Clicks"));

        frameMain.add(labelcps);
        frameMain.add(labelCount);

        for(int i = 0; i<buttonAuto.size(); i++){
            buttonAuto.get(i).addActionListener(new buttonBuyAction() );
        buttonAuto.get(i).setActionCommand(Integer.toString(i));
        frameMain.add(buttonAuto.get(i));
        }


        running = true;
    }

    /*
    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(!running)
            return;
        running = false;

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    */

    static void tick(){
        //do stuff
        for(AutoClicker clicker: clickers){
            clickCount += (clicker.getCPS() / 60)* clicker.getNumberOwned();
            System.out.println("added " + (clicker.getCPS() / 60)* clicker.getNumberOwned()
                    + " from " + clicker.getNumberOwned() + " " + clicker.getName() +"'s");
        }
    }
    static void render(){
        double cpst = 0;
        for(AutoClicker clicker: clickers){
            cpst += (clicker.getCPS())* clicker.getNumberOwned();
        }
        labelCount.setText("[ Click Count: " + (int)clickCount + " ]");
        labelcps.setText("[ Click Per Second: " + ((int)(cpst*10))/10.0 + " ]");

        for(int i = 0; i < clickers.size(); i++){
            if((int)clickers.get(i).getCost()>clickCount){
                if(buttonAuto.get(i).isEnabled())
                    buttonAuto.get(i).setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                if(!buttonAuto.get(i).isEnabled())
                    buttonAuto.get(i).setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And here is my AutoClicker class:

```
public class AutoClicker {
    private static String name;
    private static double cps;
    private static double cost;
    private static int numberOwned;

    public AutoClicker(String nameIn, double cpsIn, int costIn){
        name = nameIn;
        cps = cpsIn;
        cost = costIn;
        numberOwned = 0;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public double getCPS(){
        return cps;
    }
    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
    public int getNumberOwned(){
        return numberOwned;
    }

    public void buy(){
        numberOwned++;
        cost*=1.174;
    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch! ^_^

Comment: You're modifying the state of the UI from outside of the context of the EDT, this is going to lead you down a dangerous path of thread race conditions as your update loop competes with the passive rendering engine of Swing.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Get rid of most all of your static modifiers. Especially all in the AutoClicker class. When these fields are static, they become fields of the class not the object, and so each AutoClicker object shares the same field with all the others -- not what you want.

In fact, likely the only thing that should be static should be the main method, and that's it. Then you can change this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    init();
    run();
}
```

to this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Main main = new Main();
    main.init();
    main.run();
}
```

---

Also

- You have declared the cpst variable twice, one as a field of the class and one local to the `render()` method, and this last one shadows the class field -- are you sure that you want to do this?
- As mentioned in comment, you're calling the code in the `run()` method in the main thread. If your code were started appropriately, this would be called in the Swing event thread and would completely freeze your program. If you then corrected this and placed the Runnable in a Thread and called `start()` on it, now you'd be mutating Swing components from within a background thread -- all dangerous things to do. Please read: Lesson: Concurrency in Swing to see how to fix this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: all except the main method. Congrats on reaching 200,000, BTW.